# Как переделать для тега img src на урл из внешнего стореджа ASP net Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, rewrite, middleware

У меня в проекте есть множество страниц, представлений, где есть изображения. В данный момент в проекте изображения берутся из локальной папки с проектом.
Пример:

`<img src="images/banner.jpeg" class="img-responsive" alt="banner">`

Пути указаны относительные.
Кроме того, папка со статическими файлами не wwwroot, а другая. Для этого есть код:

```
StaticFileOptions options = new StaticFileOptions();
options.FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(staticFolder.Value);
options.RequestPath = new PathString(staticFolder.Key);
options.OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
{
    ctx.Context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public,max-age=" + websiteSettings.ImageCacheControlDurationInSeconds;
};

app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы картинки смотрели по абсолютному пути, к примеру, https://cdntest.azureedge.net/content/products/images/banner.jpeg

Менять по всему проекту src в img не вариант.

Может можно как-то перехватить с помощью middleware и менять пути или через url rewrite это сделать.

Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Нашёл вариант с url rewrite, но что-то не работает

```
            <outboundRules>
                <rule name="cdn" preCondition="html">
                    <match filterByTags="Img" pattern="^images/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="https://cdntest.azureedge.net/content/products/images/banner.jpeg" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="html">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                </preConditions>
            </outboundRules>
```

Comment: Ну захардкодьте в src имя сервера. Вообще, чтобы указывать полный url - нужно знать адрес сайта. Это автоматически вызывает проблемы, если надо неплоить на два сайта и более и неудобно при смене адреса сайта. Кроме того, если таким способом пытаются отделаться от краулеров крадущих контент - им на это давно пофигу, распарсят любой адрес. Так что непонятно ни зачем так делать, ни что мешает так сделать уже сейчас.

Comment: @AK У меня тысячи мест, где используется img с таким src. Я же не буду перебирать все файлы по всему проекту и править пути

Comment: Мне удалось найти ответ на вопрос: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68667471/6589692](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68667471/6589692)